# deleteCharactersInRange work something wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablestring

HI all! I am using message deleteCharactersInRange from NSMutableString. And there is a problem that this finction deletes range in a wrong way.
Here is a sample of code that works wrong:

-(void) btnClick
{
NSRange deleteRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
[valueStr deleteCharactersInRange:deleteRange];
[self ShowNumber];
}

I have a mutable string: "-21.256" and when I press the button btnClick it must delete "-" from the begining but it does it only after the 5th presses time. Ealier it worked fine, but now no. Help please, or what can I use instead this function? Thanx!

Comment: The `deleteCharactersInRange` should work just fine, did you try adding NSLog's in at the start and end of the method, to check what the values of `valueStr` are before and after the `deleteCharactersInRange` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be interesting to you.
I itinialized my string in a such way:

```
NSString *buf = nil;
buf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%14.5f", myCalculator.calcValue];
```

after that I add this string to my NSMutableString. And with string I did operations with the help of func:

```
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

But charachters were deleted only after the 6 or 7 cycle of clicking.

**Solution:**

The problem is in **@"%14.5f"**   in this string we have:
"      -2.00000"instead of "-2.00000" so function does her work well, but it deleted white spaces instead of "-".

So we need to convert in such way: **@"%f"**

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"-21.256"];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

results in:

```
-21.256
21.256
```

Your problem must be elsewhere.